# how to replace comma separated string in ajax response?

Tags: javascript, replace

i have this type of ajax response in loop

```
success: function (data) {
               var len = data.length;
               for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                   var res = data[i]['columnList'];
                   alert(res); 
               }

           }
```

alert result like this

```
 INV.TxnID,INV.CustomerListID,INV.RefNumber,INV.BillAddress1,INV.TotalAmt
```

how to replace INV. with Blank in res whole varible result?

thank you

Comment: Check your input, that is invalid syntax, nor does it look like you've tried anything so far...

Comment: It's not even valid JS syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
 document.write(
 
 "INV.TxnID,INV.CustomerListID,INV.RefNumber,INV.BillAddress1,INV.TotalAmt"
.replace(/INV./g ,""))
```

Answer (score 1):

i have get the solution

```
success: function (data) {
               var len = data.length;
               for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                   var res = data[i]['columnList'];

                    var result = res.replace(/INV./g, "");
               }
             alert(result);
           }
```

like this replace .INV string to null in all comma seperated string result